# Why did $(':radio').change() stop working in new jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am testing the following code with two jQuery versions: 1.5.1 and 1.7.2

```
$(':radio').change(function(){alert(1)});
```

It works in the old jQuery and not in the new one. Why do I have to use `.click()` in the new version?

Browser: Chrome 18

Comment: please create a test case on jsfiddle.net that demonstrates your assertion.

Comment: it works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zsMAX/

Comment: did you try `[type="radio"]` too? it should be a faster selector after all, as it can be used in QSA -> http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

Comment: @GNi33. Though it's true, it's not the issue here at all...

Comment: Also specify the browser[s] tested. There has historically been quirks with change events -- when they "occur" in particular.

Comment: @gdoron i know. didn't test the specified selector, so i thought that maybe it could help. it was a comment after all ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" checked /> Radio 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2"/> Radio 2 <br/>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(':radio').change(function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });​
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zsMAX/ is set up to use jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: Yep, it works on jsfiddle. I have read several questions here and everybody suggests .click() instead of .change(). I will try to track down why jQuery version affects my code.

Comment: @Andrei. Who is "everybody"? it's exactly the same... anyway, it might be related to `.attr()` V.S. `.prop()`

Comment: I have a number of plugins and own code on the page. I guess something interferes. It was a bit strange that jQuery version influences this

Comment: @gdoron, yes, it was actually `.prop('checked',true)` which used to trigger `.change()`. Thanks a lot for the hint!